# Phonegap Build Error : Oh geez. Your build failed

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Problem : I am using **Phonegap Build** framework for my iOS app developent. While [building](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) I added .p12 and .mobile provision certificate to the app and unlocked. While rebuild, I faced strange error "*Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build server*". 
[image]
So, as usual when I done google, I [found here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/oh_geez_your_build_failed_sorry_but_a_problem_occurred_on_the_build_server-wqi3u) which says we need to place third party plugin after placing phonegap/cardova plugins. But, Still no luck !.
I am using 8 phonegap plugin and 1 third party plugin. Please refer below comfig xml file.

My config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
 <widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.my.app"
    version   = "1.0">

<name>My app name</name>

<description>
  my first app in phonegap
</description>

<author href="http://myself.com" email="support@myself.com">
    myself
</author>

<preference name="permissions"                value="none"/>
<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="phonegap-version"           value="3.3.0" />    <!-- all: current version of PhoneGap -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="false" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="10" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />


 <!-- make the statusbar hiden from webview -->
 <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" /> 
 <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />

 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" /> 
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" /> -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" /> -->
<!-- <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" /> -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<!--  <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />  -->
<gap:plugin name="com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.lowlatencyaudio" />

 <access origin="*" />   

  <!-- Defined splash screen  and icons here and works fine ... -->
```

Question : What is the real cause for this error ? Any clear and quick solution for this?

/*** ** UPDATE ** ***/

I am able to overcome this error!! But only if I add those unnecessary plugins [uncommented remaining 11 plugins in config.xml file].
Is there any solution to avoid these plugins and solve this error ? Any help greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the commented lines?

Comment: @DawsonLoudon :  YES ! If I build without commented plugins, it will work. But I don't want to include those plugins since I am not using those.

Comment: Right, I am suggesting instead of commenting them out, delete those lines as they are not needed. I am wondering if the commented lines are causing a build error? So maybe try removing them all together and it might resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />

<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
<plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.Geolocation" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
    <true/>
</gap:config-file>
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
    <false/>
</gap:config-file>    

<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />  
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustResize" />
```

Update your config.xml like above code. I think it is work. It is my error like you;

> Oh geez. Your build failed. Sorry, but a problem occurred on the build
>   server notify us

Second solution. If your config.xml geolocation version is 0.3.10
   replace with 0.3.7

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.10" />
```

Replace with this

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" version="0.3.7" />
```